# I want to show my popup just one time in a day

Tags: html, cookies

I want to show this popup just one time in a one day, how can I do that?

```
    <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>x</span>
<iframe width="360" height="240" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MXaa9lBJq0I" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple

Use Javascript to

1.) get current time
2.) check time of cookie
3.) if difference of cookie time and current time is bigger then 24 hours :
Save new date in cookie
Show iframe

Save cookie

> var d = new Date(); 
>   document.cookie="time="+d;

Read Cookie with dokument.cookie